# p-adic expansion of roots of unity

Tags: p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

Let $w$ be an n-th root of unity, I have two questions

1) What are the conditions on the prime $p$ such that $w\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, and if it is the case what is the p-adic expansion of an n-th root of unity in that case (do we have a closed formula of this expansion)

2) What about the other cases i.e when $w$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and belongs to a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, do we have an expression in terms of generators of this extension.

Comment: I think this question is more suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/. But briefly, you can find what you need in most books about $p$-adic numbers. For example, have a look at Gouvea's "p-adic Numbers: An introduction" book. Specifically, Proposition 3.4.2.

Comment: Sure, what about the p-adic expansion ?

Comment: Again, the basic ideas on how to do this is covered in the book. Just think, can you solve $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ and then $\mod p^2$ and so on?

Comment: Well, we can use the Hensel lemma, what I'm looking for is an expression of the coefficients, a formula for the expansion

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you can find the coefficients, in a explicit way, by solving the equation modulo higher powers of $p$. Have a think of how to do this (or look at the book). So, if you know how to solve equations modulo some power of $p$ then you know how to find your coefficients.

Comment: I tried to solve it by Hensel's Lemma but the calculations are somewhat cumbersome, I'm looking for another approach if possible ?

Comment: Another approach, 143983, is to post to mathstackexchange, as has been suggested to you. But be sure to include everything you already know about the question, or else it will get closed, and be sure to include your objections to Hensel, or else you'll have to go through this all over again.

Comment: It seems that very little is known about $p$-adic or related expansions: see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/173722/17064), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/238078/17064) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/156301/17064) for somewhat related questions, on which sadly nobody had anything interesting to say.

Comment: I've had interest in algebraic $p$-adic expansions using $p^\mathbb{Q}$ e.g. $\sqrt{-1}=1+2^{1/2}+2^{3/4}+2^{7/8}+ ... + \zeta_{3}2 + ...$

Answer (score 5):

For $p$ odd

- $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times = \langle\zeta_{p-1}\rangle \times (1+p)^{\Bbb{Z}_p}$ where $\zeta_{p-1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} g^{p^n}$ for $g \in \Bbb{Z}$ of order $p-1$ in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$.
- If $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is  a finite extension whose residue field is $O_K/(\pi) \cong \Bbb{F}_{p^f}$ then take $g\in O_K$ of order $p^f-1 $ modulo $(\pi)$ you'll have $\zeta_{p^f-1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} g^{p^{fn}}$.
- For $p \nmid m$ let $f$ be the order of $p \bmod m$, $O_{\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^f-1})}=O_{\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_m)}= \sum_{l=0}^{f-1} \zeta_m^l\Bbb{Z}_p$, it is a complete DVR with uniformizer $p$ of valuation $1$ and residue field $\Bbb{F}_{p^f}$. For the Galois actions you might prefer a normal basis for $\Bbb{F}_{p^f}/\Bbb{F}_p$.
- $O_{\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_m,\zeta_{p^r})} =\sum_{m=0}^{(p-1)p^{r-1}-1}(\zeta_{p^r}-1)^m  O_{\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_m)}$ with uniformizer $\zeta_{p^r}-1$ of valuation $(p-1)p^{r-1}$ and residue field $\Bbb{F}_{p^f}$. In particular $\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^r})/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified of degree $(p-1)p^{r-1}$.

Knowing a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ means knowing its uniformizer, residue field and how the Galois group acts on both.

Comment: I'm looking for the general expression of coefficients!

Comment: That's the general expression. The "coefficients" of what ? ${}{}$

Comment: of the p-adic expansion of a given n-th root of unity as in David Lampert comment six minutes ago

Comment: I gave it : it is $\zeta = g^{p^n} \bmod p^n$. Do you understand that $p$-adic series and $p$-adic limit is the same ?

Comment: Can you be more explicit please

Comment: What is not explicit to you ?

Comment: well if $\omega^n=1$ then I would like to write it as $\omega=1+\alpha_1p+\alpha_2p^2+..... $

Comment: If $\omega$ is a $p-1$-primitive root then $\omega = \lim g^{a p^n}$ for some $a$ coprime with $p-1$. The RHS is a limit in the same way that a series such as $\sum_{n \ge 0} p^n$ is a limit.

Comment: so what are the $\alpha_i$ equal to ??

Comment: To the reduction of $g^{p^n} \bmod p^n$, as for any $p$-adic series.

Comment: Do you mean $\omega=1+g^p+g^{p^2}+g^{p^3}+....$

Comment: Not at all. I mean a p-adic a series is a p-adic limit, you need to understand why both are the same (ie. understand the definition of $\Bbb{Q}_p$)

Comment: I think I understand now,  $w=g^{p^n}\mod p^n$ and we need to factor out $g^{p^n}$ to find the p-adic expansion of $\omega$

Comment: Let $g$ an integer of order $p-1$ modulo $p$ and $w_n$ be the unique integer in $[0,p^n-1]$ that is $\equiv g^{p^n} \bmod p^n$, then $c_n = \frac{w_n-w_{n-1}}{p^n} 
 \in 0 \ldots p-1$ and the $p$-adic series $w_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n p^n$ is equal to $\lim_{n \to \infty} g^{p^n}$ thus it is your primitive $p-1$ root of unity.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, though I think it's a little bit hard to find $\omega_n$ explicitly, it depends on the prime $p$.

Comment: There isn’t a formula for the digits of a root of unity, any more than there’s a formula for the real digits of $\sqrt2$. But you can start with any integer $n$ prime to $p$, and go $z_0=n\mapsto n^p=z_1$ and then $z_n\mapsto z_n^p=z_{n+1}$. You get more digit with each iteration. The limit is the root of unity $\equiv n\pmod p$.